# How to make MySQL code shorter?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, filter

Im trying to do a date filter for my report generate form. I have a DateTimePicker with checkbox in this form, If checkbox checked the query will add a WHERE clause.

Currently Im doing this way:-

```
         If DateTimePicker1.Checked Then
              query = "SELECT payment_type, sales_payment_dtl.payment_amt, payment_remark, sales_payment_dtl.created_date, sales.inv_no
                    FROM sales_payment_dtl
                    INNER JOIN sales_payment
                    ON sales_payment_dtl.payment_id = sales_payment.payment_id
                    INNER JOIN sales
                    ON sales_payment.sales_id = sales.sales_id
                    WHERE sales_payment_dtl.created_date = '"& DateTimePicker.Text &"'"
         Else
              query = "SELECT payment_type, sales_payment_dtl.payment_amt, payment_remark, sales_payment_dtl.created_date, sales.inv_no
                    FROM sales_payment_dtl
                    INNER JOIN sales_payment
                    ON sales_payment_dtl.payment_id = sales_payment.payment_id
                    INNER JOIN sales
                    ON sales_payment.sales_id = sales.sales_id"
         End If
```

Is it possible to make the code shorter? Because I need to add somemore filter in future, then the code will become very long, Maybe something like this?

```
 query = "SELECT payment_type, sales_payment_dtl.payment_amt, payment_remark, sales_payment_dtl.created_date, sales.inv_no
                    FROM sales_payment_dtl
                    INNER JOIN sales_payment
                    ON sales_payment_dtl.payment_id = sales_payment.payment_id
                    INNER JOIN sales
                    ON sales_payment.sales_id = sales.sales_id

                    IF '"& DateTimePicker.Checked = True &"' THEN 
                    WHERE sales_payment_dtl.created_date = '"& DateTimePicker.Text &"'
                    ELSE 
                    do nothing"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on [**Code Review**](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple logic.

```
    query = "SELECT payment_type, sales_payment_dtl.payment_amt, payment_remark, sales_payment_dtl.created_date, sales.inv_no " & _
    "FROM(sales_payment_dtl) " & _
    "INNER JOIN sales_payment " & _
    "ON sales_payment_dtl.payment_id = sales_payment.payment_id " & _
    "INNER JOIN sales " & _
    "ON sales_payment.sales_id = sales.sales_id"

    If DateTimePicker1.Checked Then
        query &= " WHERE sales_payment_dtl.created_date = '" & DateTimePicker.Text & "'"
    End If
```